# unable to submit question about modern fighter jets

Tags: support, tags, asking-questions

I get a message that says:

> You are attempting to create the tag [jets]; however the tag [jet] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta"

I have searched for an answer to my question but unable to find an answer or any similar question posted.

The question I have in mind is:

Are modern fighter jets equipped with some type of wiper system on the exterior of their canopies?

Comment: Why can't the question be submitted? Can you share the message that you get?

Comment: " You are attempting to create the tag [jets]; however the tag [jet] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta"
The above response in quotation marks is what I receive when I try to submit.... I  have searched for an answer to my question but unable to find an answer or any similar question posted...Thank you ...Gary V.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [jet] tag, it means the same thing as [jet**s**].